# If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0,1]$, show that g(x) is continuous on [0,1].

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0,1]$, show that g(x) is continuous on [0,1] where g  is equal to f on (0,1] and g(0)= $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$. Assume limit exists.

It is obvious that g(x) is continuous (0,1]. So i want to show that g(x) is continous at 0.

I am trying to use the definition of continuity and one sided limits and put them together.

One side limit: limit of f as x approaches 0+ exists and equals L if for all epsilon,there exists an r>0:

|f(x)-L| < epsilon for all 0< x < r.

Continuity at a: g is continuous at 0 if for every epsilon > 0, there exists an r>0 such that for all x [0,1] with |x-0| < r, |g(x)-g(0)| < epsilon

Comment: Just to clarify, does the one sided limit exist? Your question phrasing seems to suggest that it must, but this need not be true of all continuous functions on $(0,1]$, like $\frac {1}{x}$.

Comment: Isn't the key point whether $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$ exists?  Are you being given this as part of your hypotheses?  If so, there is almost nothing to say: this is the definition of continuity of a point at an endpoint of an interval.  If not, you need to have some additional information to deduce this.

Comment: Aha, based on your last question it seems it is the latter and the extra hypothesis is **uniform continuity** on $(0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, we assume the limit exists, sorry about that

Comment: @maria: I think you are confused.  Anyway, please treat my answer below as an answer to your linked-to (and currently closed) question, which I think is what you really want to know about.

Comment: THanks, but i still want to know how to prove this question. I will  remove the link.

Comment: Then I'm confused, because what you give is the standard definition of continuity of a function at an endpoint of an interval.  Do you understand the relationship between limits at a point and continuity at a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are assuming that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=L$ exists, and defining $g(0)=L$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and find the appropriate $r>0$ for the one-sided limit definition.

Note that $x\in[0,1]$ and $|x-0|<r$ if and only if $x\in[0,1]$ and $0\leq x<r$.

We know that for $x\in[0,1]$ with $0<x$, we have $g(x)=f(x)$, so $$|g(x)-g(0)|=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ whenever $x\in[0,1]$ with $0<x<r$. Hence, to show continuity of $g$ at $x=0$, it remains to show that $|g(0)-g(0)|<\epsilon$, which is trivial.